# Tcl/Expect file idling for no apparent reason?

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm trying to write a code in Expect/Tcl after going through a few tutorials. I've got some success in executing my script. But a problem I have is that my script idles for a while before executing the next exp_send command. Googling, brought be to a suggestion of putting in a small sleep, before the exp_send, but that didn't seem to make any different. Here's my relevant code:

```
    exp_send "\r"
 expect "\ $"
    exp_send "\r"
    expect "\ $"
    exp_send "\r" <---- Idle waiting here!
    expect {
     "\r" {
         exp_continue
        }
    }
 expect eof
```

I am sending information in the exp_send statements, but I don't think its of any significance, so I haven't posted it ..

Comment: add `exp_internal 1` to the top of your script so expect can show you what it is thinking. Your use of exp_continue is possibly creating an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

The information that you're sending in the exp_send IS of relevance, since could be that it´s the command that you're executing that's causing the idling

Comment: They are just dummy entries after logging onto a unix box. I'm just doing a check like "php -v" or "perl -v" etc...

Comment: Is there a set waittime variable that I could perhaps change?

Answer (score 0):

"... Expect ... idling ..." INVARIABLY presages a narrative with lots of false turns that ends up discovering that, oops, one of the "expect $pattern"-s someone thought was matching did *not* match, and was instead simply timing out.  The correct resolution will be to match the $pattern-s the coder thinks should be matched.  Correct resolution does NOT involve adjusting wait times.

http://wiki.tcl.tk/3173 has pertinent tips.